# How to obtain dataframe from grouped element after using apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say this the dataframe:

```
First Name  Last Name   Val1 
George      Clooney      N     
George      Clooney      N   
George      Clooney      Y
George      Freeman      N
George      Freeman      N
Claire      Stark        N
Claire      Stark        Y
```

Then the goal is to produce this:

```
First Name  Last Name   Val1  Total
George      Clooney      Y      3
George      Freeman      N      2
Claire      Stark        Y      2
```

The total `Val1` is `Y` as long as one of the instances is `Y`.

My code looks like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=['First Name', 'Last Name'])

def val_func(x):
    if (x['Val1'] == 'Y').any():
    return 'Y'
    else:
    return 'N'

cumulative = grouped.apply(val_func)
```

This works except that `cumulative` has dtype `object` and I can only access `Val1`, that is, I cannot access `First Name` or `Last Name` (Although when I run `print(cumulative)`, it does print everything).

If I try:

```
df_cumulative = pd.DataFrame(cumulative)
```

then, I just get the column with `Y` or `N`, but not the names.

How to fix this? Moreover, can I return two arguments? one for `Val1` and one for `Total`? or would I have to run another apply for `Total` and append the column to the dataframe?

Comment: Can you explain why in output dataframe are two `George Clooney`? Where is `George Freeman`? Shouldn't `Claire Stark` be `Y  2` ?

Comment: There should one be one. My bad.

Comment: @enky sorry, my bad again. I fixed it. I believe now it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use `groupby.agg` where you use `max` to get "Y" if it exists (because `Y>N`) and `count`:

```
out = df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name'], sort=False, as_index=False)\
        .agg(Val1=('Val1', 'max'), Total=('Val1', 'count'))
```

Output:

```
  First Name Last Name Val1  Total
0     George   Clooney    Y      3
1     George   Freeman    N      2
2     Claire     Stark    Y      2
```

You can pass in a lambda that selects based whatever criteria you want. For example, the following aggregates "Val1" based on whether the number of "Y"s are greater than the number of "N"s (if there are more "Y"s select "Y" else "N"):

```
out = df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name'], sort=False, as_index=False)\
        .agg(Val1=('Val1', lambda x: 'Y' if x.eq('Y').sum() > x.eq('N').sum() else 'N'), 
             Total=('Val1', 'count'))
```

Comment: is there a way to use arbitrary functions instead ```'max'``` or ```'count'``` or any of the predefined functions?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
(df.sort_values('Val1')
 .groupby(['First Name','Last Name'])
 .agg(Val1 = ('Val1','max'),count = ('Val1','count'))
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  First Name Last Name Val1  count
0     Claire     Stark    Y      2
1     George   Clooney    Y      3
2     George   Freeman    N      2
```

Comment: How would you do it in general (applying an arbitrary function)? For example suppose that the output is ```Y``` if there are the same amount of ```Y``` and ```N``` for that person. Otherwise the output is ```N```.